# RTTI on a nested class, VS Bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The following code ouputs:

`struct Property<int>::IValue`

But I would expect it to output:

`struct Property<int>::Value<int>`

Code:

```
struct IProperty
{
    virtual ~IProperty() = 0;
};

IProperty::~IProperty(){}

template<typename T>
struct Property : IProperty
{
    struct IValue
    {
        virtual ~IValue() = 0;
    };

    template<typename Q>
    struct Value : IValue
    {
        Q thing;
    };

    Property() : m_pValue(new Value<T>()){}
    std::shared_ptr<IValue> m_pValue;
};

template<typename T>
Property<T>::IValue::~IValue(){}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<IProperty> p(new Property<int>);

    std::cout << typeid(*static_cast<Property<int>&>(*p).m_pValue).name() << '\n';
}
```

If `IValue` and `Value` are moved outside of `Property` so that they are not nested classes anymore, I get the results I expect. Is this a VS Bug or expected behavior?

Comment: FWIW both g++4.6.3 and clang++3.2 on linux give `Property<int>::Value<int>` (after piping the output through `c++filt -t`)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, it returns the static type instead of the dynamic type, and the static type is an abstract baseclass. I have a few questions though: I believe the nested struct Value<Q> needs to have a destructor defined, since it is pure virtual in the baseclass, though I'd have to look that up. What if you make the dtor non-pure virtual? The same also applies to struct Property<T>. Further, what happens if you split the `typeid()` up into multiple expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely this is Visual C++ compiler bug. For some strange reason compiler fails to determine that `Property<T>::IValue` dereferenced from `shared_ptr` is polymorphic base class and uses static type info for `typeid` expression instead of run-time type info.

Minimal code to reproduce the bug:

```
template <class T> struct Property
{
   struct IValue
   {
      void f() {}
      virtual ~IValue() = 0 {}
   };

   struct Value: IValue {};

   Property(): m_pValue(new Value())
   {
      // typeid inside class works as expected
      std::cout << "Inside class: " << typeid(*m_pValue).name() << std::endl;
   }

   // If changed to unique_ptr typeid will work as expected
   // But if changed to raw pointer the bug remains!
   std::shared_ptr<IValue> m_pValue;
};

int main()
{
   Property<int> p;
   // If next line uncommented typeid will work as expected
   //p.m_pValue->f();
   std::cout << "Outside class: " << typeid(*p.m_pValue).name() << std::endl;
}
```

I played a bit with this sample and discovered that `typeid` starts to work as expected and show run-time type name if some function from pointed object is called before `typeid` or if `shared_ptr` is replaced with `unique_ptr`. Funny, but replacing `shared_ptr<IValue>` with `IValue*` still reproduces the bug!

**Actual output:**

```
Inside class: struct Property<int>::Value
Outside class: struct Property<int>::IValue
```

**Expected (correct) output:**

```
Inside class: struct Property<int>::Value
Outside class: struct Property<int>::Value
```

From assembler listing it's clear that it's really compiler problem:

`typeid` called from `Property` ctor generates honest call to `__RTtypeid`:

```
; 225 : std::cout << typeid(*m_pValue).name() << std::endl;
  ... irrelevant code skipped ...
; __type_info_root_node
  push  OFFSET ?__type_info_root_node@@3U__type_info_node@@A
  mov ecx, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
; std::tr1::shared_ptr<Property<int>::IValue>::operator*
  call ??D?$shared_ptr@UIValue@?...<skipped>
  push eax
  call ___RTtypeid
```

`typeid` called externally generates static `IValue` type info:

```
; 237  :    std::cout << typeid(*p.m_pValue).name() << std::endl;
  ... irrelevant code skipped ...
; __type_info_root_node
  push  OFFSET ?__type_info_root_node@@3U__type_info_node@@A
  mov ecx, OFFSET ??_R0?AUIValue@?$Property@H@@@8
```

Note also that the same bug presents in VS2008, so it's old time behavior.